# java arrays finding duplicates and replacing them

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static int[] isthereDuplicates(int[] combination) {
    Set<Integer> foundedNumbers = new HashSet<>();

    for (int i= 0; index < combination.length; i++) {
        if (foundedNumbers.contains(combination[i])) {
                combination[i] -= 1;
        } else {
            foundedNumbers.add(combination[i]);
        }

    return combination;
}
```

i need to find and replace duplicates in an array of numbers. number array is also made  with random selection of 7  numbers between 1 and 40.This code that i presented works if i have one duplicate  but when i have several for example i have 1,14,20,1,38,1,5. it will change for middle 1 but for second 1 it will remain the same.

Comment: Why do you define a HashSet an then never use it? (`nadjeniBrojevi`)

Comment: When you translate variable names into english (why aren't english in the first place?), then please translate all variable names. Your param and the Set still need to be  translated.

Comment: Can you tell us for the input you posted (1,14,20,1,38,1,5), what is the result you're looking for ?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do this, but wouldn't be easier to generate 7 unique numbers between 1-40?

Comment: Sorry Tom now i changed and translated everything.  and Sofiane about the input it is not important  what are the elements of the array, in my code i have to generate random numbers for the array and i just want to see that all different numbers, and what i saw when i tested my code is that when i have more than one element the same it gets messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work with small modifications and bit translation.

```
public static int[] imaliDuplikata(int[] combination) {
    Random r = new Random();
    Set<Integer> foundeNumbers = new HashSet<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < combination.length; i++) {
        if (foundeNumbers.contains(combination[i])) {
            combination[i] = r.nextInt(40);
        } else {
            foundeNumbers.add(combination[i]);
        }

    }
    return combination;
}
```

Executed in this way:

```
int[] i = {1,14,20,1,38,1,5};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(imaliDuplikata(i)));
```

You will get **all** occurrences of repeated numbers replaced.

Various executions:

```
[1, 14, 20, 0, 38, 35, 5]
[1, 14, 20, 11, 38, 1, 5]
[1, 14, 20, 22, 38, 30, 5]
[1, 14, 20, 37, 38, 39, 5]
```

Comment: It may return duplicated values, i.e: `[1, 14, 20, 38, 38, 39, 5]`
`r.nextInt(40);` can return the same number all the time

Comment: Jordi, i beleive that it worked, cause i try 10 times and i never had duplicates. but i will try to dig out some other solution just to be sure that it will be always ok.

Comment: Mapet what @Uata says is correct, you can have duplicates with this solution because you get a random number but you can add a while to check if random int is already in Map and not adding it and otherwise, get a new random value...

Answer (score 0):

I believe this solves your question:

First your determine the numbers in your array and you record them as not being found yet.

then you go over the numbers and when you find one that has not been found you mark it as found.

when you find the number again you do whatever you want to do with it ( in this case I put it to a value -1 )

```
public static int[] duplicates(int[] combination) {
            HashMap<Integer, Boolean> foundNumbers = new HashMap<>();
            for (int i : combination) {
                if(foundNumbers.containsKey(i)) continue;
                foundNumbers.put(i, false);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < combination.length; i++) {
                if(!foundNumbers.get(combination[i])) {
                    foundNumbers.put(combination[i], true);
                } else {
                    combination[i] = -1;
                }
            }

            return combination;
        }
```

Comment: Arno i tried your code also, cause i understood you  steps but it keeps making duplicates.Thanks anyway.